# Iron router confuse two routes if the only difference is an ID parameter?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have two routes and it seems that iron router confuses both. I wanted to check if it is true before looking into the rest of the code.

Here are my two routes (note that the controller name is not the same - `group` instead of `groups`):

```
this.route("groups.trashbin", {
  path: "/groups/trashbin",
  controller: "GroupsTrashbinController"
});

this.route("group.trashbin", {
  path: "/groups/trashbin/:groupId",
  controller: "GroupTrashbinController"
});
```

Is it normal that the second one is always used, even if my `pathFor` refers to the first?

Comment: What version of Iron Router are you using? It looks really old.

Comment: I am using version 1.0.7. I will update it and check if it still happens

Comment: after update, I end up with a mongo related error: [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] . Murphy law in action. :'(

Comment: IR shouldn't confuse these routes. They have different names and different paths. What does your pathFor code look like and what does it return?

Comment: `{{pathFor "groups.trashbin"}}` (the first route) was going to the second and the `groupId` parameter was empty. I'll put this on hold since I just lost my code (4 days of work). I messed up while trying to update IR, and now I am back to my last git push...